Azure KeyVault Support for Custom OIds
I have a few custom OID extensions in my X509 certificates.  When I import them to Azure KeyVault, I get the "one or more x.509 properties are invalid" error.  When I remove this extension, the import works without fail.
Is there a way to configure KeyVault to accept my custom OIDs and extensions?

Key Vault does not support custom OIDs at this time.
If you would like to request additional features, please file a request on https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/285c5ae0-f524-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0.
